# Xcode GPS Simulation

Tags: objective-c, gps, ios9, xcode7, gpx

Recently I tried to simulate different GPS locations in Xcode using the GPX file option however when disconnecting my device and launching the app that simulates the location, it no longer works. Do I have to always connect it to the computer and click simulate location for it to work or can the app integrate the simulation independent of Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently being doing some testing and it seems that unplugging the device during the simulation will freeze the GPS' coordinates at the current standpoint. This can be undone by restarting the device.

(Previously I stopped running it, unplugged 'safely' and launched the app)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode simulates the location of your iDevice, which means you have to keep it connected to your Mac while simulating.

Comment: False, I just found out how to keep (at least part of) the simulation running.